# Spark on Yarn: How to prevent multiple spark jobs being scheduled

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

With spark on yarn - I dont see a way to prevent concurrent jobs being scheduled. I have my architecture setup for doing purely batch processing.

I need this for the following reasons:

- Resource Constraints
- UserCache for spark grows really quickly. Having multiple jobs run causes an explosion of space on cache.

Ideally I'd love to see if there is a config that would ensure only one job to run at any time on Yarn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run create a queue which can host only one application master and run all Spark jobs on that queue. Thus, if a Spark job is running the other will be accepted but they won't be scheduled and running until the running execution has finished...

Comment: I am using HDP from HortonWorks. I see there is a queue being used but dont see how to configure it to ensure only one is run. Any tips on which config to look for?

Comment: You can find here some documentation by Hortonworks about queue management (https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_performance_tuning/content/section_create_configure_yarn_capacity_scheduler_queues.html). As you can see one of the settings for a queue is the maximum number of applications admitted...

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution - was in yarn documents: yarn.scheduler.capacity.max-applications has to be set to 1 instead of 10000.