# How can I queue REST requests using Apache Livy and Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, rest, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a remote process that sends a thousands requests to my humble **Spark Standalone Cluster**:

- 3 worker-nodes with 4 cores and 8GB
- Identical master-node where the driver runs

that hosts a simple data processing service developed in Scala. Those requests are sent via **cUrl** command with some parameters to the .jar, through the REST [Apache Livy](https://github.com/cloudera/livy) interface like this:

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" REMOTE_IP:8998/batches -d '{"file":"file://PATH_TO_JAR/target/MY_JAR-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar","className":"project.update.MY_JAR","args":["C1:1","C2:2","C3:3"]}'
```

- This triggers a spark job each time,
- the resource scheduling for the cluster is dynamic so it can serve at most 3 requests at a time,
- when a worker goes idle, another queued request is served.

At some point in time, the requests kills the master node memory even if they are in a **WAITING** state (because Spark register the jobs to be served), hangs the master node and the workers loose connection to it.

Is there a way that I can queue this requests preventing that Spark hold RAM for them ? and when a worker is free, process another request from that queue.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590856/spark-on-yarn-how-to-prevent-multiple-spark-jobs-being-scheduled?rq=1) question is similar, saying that the *yarn.scheduler.capacity.max-applications* only allows N numbers of RUNNING applications, but I can't figure it out if this is the solution I need. Apache Livy doesn't have this functionality, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Options: 1) reduce cores/memory each job uses if possible to allow more jobs, 2) use a second queue to hold the backlog of jobs, 3) run a persistent spark job that queues/runs the other jobs concurrently.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit about the third option ? Is quite interesting actually, but I'm not sure how a "neverending" job would see that Livy is accepting requests, maybe some service listening at the same port as Livy ?

Comment: 3rd option could actually be orchestrated through Livy. Bring up a spark application (Livy session) that acts as your job scheduler. It takes requests in then concurrently and asynchronously submits those requests as independent applications. Disclaimer, I have not tried this approach and personally I get woozy thoughts thinking about supporting such an unusual design. YARN is my usual tool but I would also consider something Airflow by Airbnb or some other job orchestrator (maybe even a lightweight API of your own).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'd consider Airflow as well. Now I'm moving to YARN.